# An issue with MySQL query in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$users_id = $this->db->query('SELECT users_id FROM users ORDER BY daily_points desc limit 1');
$text = 'Congratulations! You are the winner for today!';
$this->game->send_message( '0', $users_id, $text, 'yes' );
```

I'd like to ask what's my mistake here with the `$users_id` ?
If I execute the query via MySQL I get the requested info but however if I run the script php, it doesn't return any value for that? Why is that?

Comment: you need to fetch it first, anyway is this CI?

Comment: yeah, it's codeigniter. would you mind to help me out how it should work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the query you need to fetch the results first:

```
$result = $this->db->query('
    SELECT users_id FROM users 
    ORDER BY daily_points desc limit 1')
->result_array(); // you need to fetch it either result()/result_array()

$text = 'Congratulations! You are the winner for today!';
$this->game->send_message( '0', $result[0]['users_id'], $text, 'yes' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've learned a lot here recently and especially by you Ghost. You're the best. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear, there is a lot of posibilities to determine what is happening.
Try debbuging your $users_id variable to see what is into it.

```
$users_id = $this->db->query('SELECT users_id FROM users ORDER BY daily_points desc limit 1');
var_dump($users_id);
$text = 'Congratulations! You are the winner for today!';
$this->game->send_message( '0', $users_id, $text, 'yes' );
```

If that is a resource then you will need to fetch the result to see that as @Ghost said.

Answer (score 0):

The query()-method returns an object. There are multiple possibilities to get the wanted value, e.g. by this:

```
$users_id = $this->db->query('
    SELECT users_id FROM users ORDER BY daily_points desc limit 1
')->row()->users_id;
```

For a reference, see the [CodeIgniter Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)